# How to create tabs in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm a beginner on windows phone 8 developpement, and I need to create a tabs system ( a little like slidingDrawer on Android).
I explain myself, i've implemented a xaml interface which look like this :

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/974529onglet.png

The code of this interface :

```
<StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="402" Width="480">
            <StackPanel Width="161" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                <StackPanel Height="50" Background="DarkCyan">
                    <TextBlock Height="50" Text="Qualité orale" Foreground="White"  />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="50" >

                    <TextBlock Text="Compréhension" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                    <TextBlock Text="Général" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                    <TextBlock Text="Fichiers relatifs" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                    <TextBlock Text="Le conférencier" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Height="50">
                    <TextBlock Text="Questions" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
```

What i want to do here is that when the user touch a stackpanel, the stackpanel change his colour and the gray content at the right change too.

Can you help me solve my problem ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add Tap attributes to the TextBlocks and handle the events from the code behind.

For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="Questions" 
           Foreground="White"
           Tap="MyEventHandler"
/>
```

Then you would want to give Name attributes to your StackPanels so that you can reference it in your code. Like so:

```
<StackPanel Height="50" Name="QuestionsStackPanel">
       <TextBlock Text="Questions" Foreground="White"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the code behind file, visual studio may auto generate the method stub, if not it should look like this.

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     //Make changes here
     QuestionsStackPanel.Background = Colors.Blue
}
```

From here you can change the colors of the specific tabs and the grey area you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First, Just for informations, the "android tabs interface" is not in agreement with the "UI (metro)" interface. It's not very very important, for more information about a "Ui design style you can go [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-6-Styling-the-App) for styling your app :d

For your Problem, in your Xaml, you can add an event for detect the click (or other event in your 'TextBlock'.

For sample, you can add a "Tap Event" in all your button in your "Code.xaml" (also, You can add a "Name" attribute for find easily your control after):

```
<StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="402" Width="480">
    <StackPanel Name ="Global_Onglets" Width="161" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
        <StackPanel Height="50" Background="DarkCyan">
            <TextBlock Height="50" 
                       Text="Qualité orale" 
                       Name="TextBlock_Quality"
                       Tap="MyPersonalEvent"
                       Foreground="White"  />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="50" >
            <TextBlock Text="Compréhension" 
                       Name="TextBlock_Comprehension"
                       Tap="MyPersonalEvent"
                       Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="50">
            <TextBlock Text="Général" 
                       Name="TextBlock_General"
                       Tap="MyPersonalEvent"
                       Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And, in your "code.cs", you create your event method :

```
/// <summary>
/// Event handler called by Textblock Tap.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void MyPersonalEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get, the current textblock where called the event.
    TextBlock CurrentTextBlock = sender as TextBlock;

    // Check just the clicked textBlock, for attributes specific colors..
    foreach (TextBlock textblock in Global_Onglets.Children)
    {
        if (textblock == sender)
        {
            // Attribute secific color for this tap textblock;

        }
       // Attribute a "normal" color for alls others textBlock..
    }
}
```

You can have more details about events [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-5-Basics-of-Layout-and-Events)!!

Also, I saw You create your app in French. But, You can easy Localized your application for create here in other languages (and distrube in other country...) if you want you've a great tutorial [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-7-Localizing-the-App) about "localizing your app"... Better think before, that any duty again later. :D